# How to determine if a filesystem path is already taken in Julia

Tags: julia

For files there is `isfile`, but what if I dont know if the path is taken up by a file or a directory?

Basically, is there a function in Julia Base that does the following:

```
function is_in_use(path)::Bool
    return isfile(path) || isdir(path)
end
```

Maybe there are more cases that can use a path that I did not think of, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Like this](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.ispath):

> Base.Filesystem.ispath — Function
>
> `ispath(path) -> Bool`
>
> Return true if a valid filesystem entity exists at path, otherwise
> returns false. This is the generalization of isfile, isdir etc.